# remove the unwanted columns in data

Tags: python, pandas

I have 500 txt files in a folder
data example:

```
1-1,0-7,10.1023,
1-2,7-8,/,
1-3,8-9,A,
1-4,9-10,:,
1-5,10-23,1020940830716,
```

I would like to delete the last "," in each line. to :

```
1-1,0-7,10.1023
1-2,7-8,/
1-3,8-9,A
1-4,9-10,:
1-5,10-23,1020940830716
```

How do I do that with a for loop to delete them from all of 500 files?

Comment: i feel you could probably do this easier with command line tools (windows/unix), given the number of files you are working with

Comment: how can I do that ? @sammywemmy

Comment: for example with bash, something like `for f in /path/to/folder/*.txt; do sed -i 's/,$//' "$f"; done` (this will overwrite the files, so make backups)

Comment: or `find /path/to/folder -iname '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/,$//' {} +` (again, make backups first!)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        string = f.read().replace(',\n','\n')
    with open(fname, 'w') as w:
        w.write(string)
```

Comment: I doubt the OP wants to overwrite the files.

Comment: all the txt files turned out all empty after i ran the code. I posted my full code down below.

Comment: The file ends up being blank

Comment: @KimiShui Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this.

1. Change the `folder_path` variable
2. Change the `filename_pattern` variable. This is just extra in case you have specific file patterns in your folder that you want to consider. You can simply set this variable to   (blank) if irrelevant.

Also, the `*` takes anything that matches the pattern i.e. Book1, Book2, etc. Before running the code `print(files)` to make sure you have all of the correct files. I am not sure if :

```
import glob
import os
import pandas

#read files in
folder_path = 'Documents'
filename_pattern = 'Book'
files = glob.glob(f'{folder_path}//{filename_pattern}*.txt')
df = (pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None)
              .assign(filename=os.path.basename(f)) 
              for f in files]))


#read files out
for file, data in df.groupby('filename'):
    data.iloc[:,:-2].to_csv(f'{folder_path}/{file}', 
                            index=False, 
                            header=False)
```

Comment: will the `rstrip` do anything here though? won't the trailing comma have already been parsed by `read_csv` into an extra `nan` column? maybe something like `df = df.iloc[:,:-1]` instead?

Comment: I tried to ```print(files''' but its an empty list []

Comment: @tdy you may be right I was using a .csv file. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: @KimiShui try now